# Effective theories and dimension six operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

What is the importance of dimension six operators in the study of physics beyond the Standard Model? Are these operators more relevant than dimension five operators like $HHFF$ or operators with derivative couplings?

I often see lagrangians with dimension six operators in effective studies of the standard model, but I do not understand this choice. An example is the paper [arXiv:1304.1151](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1151), where they have defined: $$\mathcal{L}_{\rm eff}= \sum_n \frac{g_n}{\Lambda^2}\mathcal{O_n},$$
whit $g_n$ being the corresponding couplings and $\mathcal{O}_n$ the dimension six operators.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1151

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only dimension-five operators allowed by the SM are neutrino masses, $(HL_i)(HL_j)$. So we mostly talk about dimension-six operators because for almost any question they're the first higher-dimension operators that can appear.

Comment: @Matt_Reece, thank you for your answer! Do you know why dimension-six operators with derivative couplings are never considered? I also have a by-product question: we can give mass to neutrinos in the SM using dimension-4 terms. So, why is it interesting to consider dimension-5 (non-renormalizable) operators to give them mass?

Comment: Operators with derivative couplings are considered frequently. And giving mass to neutrinos with dimension 4 operators requires the introduction of a field that isn't present in the Standard Model (a right-handed neutrino). In the Standard Model as an effective theory with fixed field content, the dimension-5 Majorana masses are the only possible neutrino mass. Which doesn't mean it's how neutrino mass works in the real world; we don't know yet.